# How do I make a conduit like takeWhile but only takes at maximum a certain number of bytes?

Tags: haskell, conduit

I'm trying to make a conduit that's sort of a cross between [`takeWhile`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.0.8/docs/Data-Conduit-Binary.html#v%3atakeWhile) and [`isolate`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.0.8/docs/Data-Conduit-Binary.html#v%3aisolate). That is, it will consume from the input and yield to the output until either the predicate no longer holds or it has reached the byte limit. I know the type signature will be

```
isolateWhile :: (Monad m) => Int -> (Word8 -> Bool) -> Conduit ByteString m ByteString
```

As an example of its use:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Data.Conduit
import qualified Data.Conduit.List   as CL
import qualified Data.Conduit.Binary as CB
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class

charToWord = fromIntegral . fromEnum

example :: Int -> Char -> IO ()
example limit upTo = do
    untaken <- CB.sourceLbs "Hello, world!" $= conduit $$ CB.sinkLbs
    putStrLn $ "Left " ++ show untaken
  where
    conduit = do
      taken <- toConsumer $ isolateWhile limit (/= charToWord upTo) =$ CB.sinkLbs
      lift $ putStrLn $ "Took " ++ show taken
      CL.map id  -- pass the rest through untouched
```

I expect that

```
ghci> example 5 'l'
Took "He"
Left "llo, world!"
ghci> example 5 'w'
Took "Hello"
Left ", world!"
```

However, the simplest possible definition of `isolateWhile`:

```
isolateWhile limit pred = CB.isolate limit =$= CB.takeWhile pred
```

yields

```
ghci> example 5 'l'
Took "He"
Left ", world!"
ghci> example 5 'w'
Took "Hello"
Left ", world!"
```

In other words, `isolate` will eat up the entire `Hello`, leaving `He` to `takeWhile` and discarding the `llo`. This data loss is undesirable for my application. However, it is notable that the second case yields the expected result.

If I swap the operands of `=$=` like so:

```
isolateWhile limit pred = CB.takeWhile pred =$= CB.isolate limit
```

Then

```
ghci> example 5 'l'
Took "He"
Left ", world!"
ghci> example 5 'w'
Took "Hello"
Left ""
```

Now I've fixed the first test, but broken the second one! This time, `takeWhile` will take whatever it needs and `isolate` will take a subset of that; but whatever `takeWhile` uses that `isolate` doesn't will be discarded, and this is undesirable.

Lastly, I tried:

```
isolateWhile limit pred = do
  untaken <- CB.isolate limit =$= (CB.takeWhile pred >> CL.consume)
  mapM_ leftover $ reverse untaken
```

This actually works! Whatever `isolate` accepts and `takeWhile` doesn't is consumed by the `CL.consume` and placed back into the stream with [`leftover`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.0.8/docs/Data-Conduit.html#v%3aleftover). Unfortunately, this seems like a horrible kludge, and undesirably (although not unusably so) it will buffer up to `limit` bytes in memory only to put it back with `leftover`. That seems like a waste.

The only solution I can think of is to write it in terms of the primitives [`await`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.0.8/docs/Data-Conduit.html#await), [`yield`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.0.8/docs/Data-Conduit.html#yield) and [`leftover`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.0.8/docs/Data-Conduit.html#v%3aleftover) as `takeWhile` and `isolate` [are themselves written](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.0.8/docs/src/Data-Conduit-Binary.html#isolate). While this would solve all the problems without wasting much, it seems like there must be a better way.

Am I missing something, or is there really no better way to write this?

Comment: Can you use [`zip`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.0.8/docs/Data-Conduit-Util.html#v:zip) together with a `[0..]`-like source, then make your `takeWhile` predicate look at both the index and the value?

Comment: @Daniel: That's a good idea that I hadn't considered, but I don't think that will work since it would count `ByteString`s, not individual bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a known limitation in the current version of conduit: fusion always discards downstream leftovers, which is exactly what you're running into here. There are some discussions right now about an architecture to resolve this, but for the moment, writing your function in terms of the primitives is likely your best option.

Comment: Thank you. I was worried that that was the case. I've written it in terms of the primitives for now, but I'd be interested to see how it would work when a resolution is reached.